# Does JTAG use DDRAM?

Tags: microcontroller, jtag, ddr

I have a microcontroller with external DDRAM. When I debug with JTAG I can see that there is code placed in the DDRAM region. However I never see the initialization of DDRAM code is run. I wonder does JTAG actually uses the DDRAM on the board? If so is the initialization of the DDRAM needed?

Thanks!

Comment: JTAG is just the interface to the MCU. It doesn't really "use" anything. It's possible that your debugging software on your PC might download something into your micro's DDRAM *through* JTAG as part of its operation.

Comment: Thanks! If the debugging software downloaded the code to the DDRAM, does the microcontroller need to run some initialization code of the DDRAM first?

Comment: Does your MCU also have integrated RAM, or is it only this external DDRAM?

Comment: It has integrated RAM. The MCU is SAMA5D36 from Microchip and the DDRAM is MT42l64m32d2HE from Micron.

Comment: As mentioned' JTAG is just the interface.  You're using a JTAG _debugger_, that has its own setup, and works with your microprocessor.  You should _edit your question_ to say _what_ debugger and micro you're using -- don't just leave it in the comments.  If you're using a specific development board, _say so_; ditto if you're using a custom circuit that's patterned off of a development board.  Note that there's no reason a sufficiently sophisticated JTAG debugger _couldn't_ use on-board DDRAM -- it'd just be a pain for someone to set it up right.

Comment: If your debugging software downloaded code into the external DDRAM, then it would have had to initialize the micro's DDRAM interface before doing that. It is possible for it to do so by using the JTAG interface to access the micro's peripheral registers - but you would almost certainly have had to tell the debugging software a little bit about the external DDRAM for it to configure things correctly.

Comment: brhans, thanks! You are right I noticed there is bootloader code that initialize the DDRAM. 
TimWescott, thanks for the suggestion. I didn't put the detailed information in the title because I think it is a more general question and it is not for a particular board.

Answer (score 3):

Your question doesn't specify what hardware you are using.  But in every implementation I have seen, JTAG is always implemented as a hardware block within a microprocessor or other chip and doesn't require any software within the target.

The intended uses of JTAG often include

- Programming a CPU that may have no code on it to begin with.
- Accessing boundary scan registers to toggle device pins for debug or to look for manufacturing defects.

JTAG typically just consists of a a shift register, a small TAP state machine, and some device specific hardware registers.  I am not sure how software would be involved in that (on the target side at least).

As for using DDRAM, no one here can say without knowing what chip you are connecting to.  Generally speaking, it's possible to do things like access internal RAM via JTAG, if the hardware is set up that way.  But JTAG shouldn't ordinarily require any RAM resources for its operation.

Comment: Thanks! The MCU is SAMA5D36 from Microchip and the DDRAM is MT42l64M32D2HE from Micron. The address of DDRAM is from 0x20000000 to 0x23FFFFFF. When I used JTAT to step through the disassembly code was shown placed in the DDRAM region. Since I don't see MCU run any DDRAM initialization code so I wonder is the address of the code shown in the DDRAM region is the actual memory content or it is from the debug software?

Comment: @user2900385 are you sure it's proper code and not just random gibberish bytes?

Comment: Yes, the code is startup code in assembly which matches the disassembly code. In disassembly code window it shows the memory address and it starts from 0x20000000.